# Error when launching Terminal in Visual Studio Code (terminated with exit code: 3221225477)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm a new user of Visual Studio Code and I came across the following error (see below) when trying to launch a Terminal inside VS Code.

`The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" terminated with exit code: 3221225477.`

I've tried fixing this by following the instructions on [Visual Studio Code Troubleshoot Terminal] (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/troubleshoot-terminal-launch) and also going through the [Get Started](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) documentation on the Visual Studio Code website.

I've also tried copying the error message and pasting on Google to search for a solution but only one relevant site came up [here](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/58863564.shtml) and I still could not find a fix.

I'm using a Dell XPS machine running Windows 10 (x64) and Visual Studio Code 1.51.0 (x64 UserSetup).

Can someone please assist? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. If your computer is running powershell, turn it off.
2. Control Panel -> Programs -> Turn Windows features on of off
3. Search Window Powershell 2.0 -> Uncheckbox -> OK
4. Restart

[image]